# How to check if a long string is a valid XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I have an string, and I want to do some things with it *if it is a valid XML*; and If not, tell the user that the string is not a valid XML.

My code is this:

```
try 
{

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(rawData);

    //And here I want to do some things with doc if it is a valid XML.
}
catch
{
    //Tell the user that the string is not a valid XML.
}
```

Now, If `rawData` contains a valid XML data, there is no problem. Also if `rawData` contains something else (like `HELLOEVERYBODY!`), It will throw an exception, So I can tell the user *the string is not a valid XML*.

**But** When `rawData` contains a HTML page, The process takes a long time (more than 20 seconds!)...

It may differ from page to page. for example, it can process `stackoverflow.com` quickly, but processing `1pezeshk.com` takes a long long time...

Isn't there any faster way to validate XML before loading it into a `XmlDocument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before and the problem is that XmlDocument tries to download the DTD for the document. In your sample this is http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd which lets you open a connection but never returns anything. So a simple solution (without any type of error checking mind you) is to remove anything before the -tag like this.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string data = wc.DownloadString("http://1pezeshk.com/");
data = data.Remove(0, data.IndexOf("<html"));
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(data);
```

### Edit

Browsing to http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd actully returns the DTD, but it took well over a minute to respond. Since you still won't do DTD-validation you should really just strip this from your HTML and then try to validate it as HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why that w3 page never returns anything? (or return something, but too late?)

Comment: I have no idea why it responds so slow, might be a temporary thing though and none of the larger browsers care about downloading the DTD anyway most won't notice.

Comment: That was my mistake. Your simple solution is working perfectly. Thank you!